# PHP5-Sybase alternativ for MSSQL connect on Windows(XAMPP) and Linux

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, xampp

im looking since hours now for an PHP extention to connect on a MSSQL Server, which can be used on Windows and Linux systems with PHP 5.3 and higher.

- PHP5-Sybase is only working for Linux.
- SQLSERV only for Windows.
- ODBC seems not working (it works but it seems like there is different syntax betwen windows and linux ??? )

im realy need something because we have to develop locally on Win7 =/

thanks a lot

Comment: You can use dblib which is already installed.

Comment: can you give me some basic infos about, i have no extension called dblib in my php/ext folder an google gives not realy answers.

Comment: What kind of info there is enough on the php manual http://www.php.net/results.php?q=dblib&l=en&p=all

Comment: thanks, i found this link and will give it a try http://docs.moodle.org/24/en/Installing_MSSQL_for_PHP

Comment: Works Fine ! 
Install dblib for Xampp:
http://docs.moodle.org/24/en/Installing_MSSQL_for_PHP

Install php5-sybase on Debian/Linux.

Both use the mssql_ syntax
http://www.php.net/manual/de/ref.mssql.php

Thanks Daan